# Is it possible to return fields in GraphQL according to a condition?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

With GraphQL, is it possible to return some fields according to a condition? For example:

```
[{
    name: "Foo",
    age: 38
}, 
{
    name: "Bar",
    age: 50
}]
```

I want to always return `name`, but `age` only if name is `Foo`. The result would be like this:

```
[{
    name: "Foo",
    age: 38
}, 
{
    name: "Bar"
}]
```

Comment: GraphQL does support optional and required fields, can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: I want to retrieve data for some fields using an condition, for example:

query {
    users {
        name
        age @include(if: ...)
    }
}

I want to return field age only if name is "Foo". The return should be:

[{
    name: "Foo",
    age: 38
}, 
{
    name: "Bar"
}]

Answer (score 0):

In your type definition you can set the required and non-required properties of a type. For instance your type may be defined as:

```
type Person {
  name: String!
  age: Int
}
```

You would have a query extension defined something along these lines:

```
extend type Query {
  getPeople: [Person]
}
```

Where you would have the logic to return different portions of this would be your resolver code. It could be something along these lines:

```
getPeople(obj, input, context) {
  // Make a request for the information from db or wherever it is stored
  // The sql or api request can do the filtering, if not it can be done after it's saved
  const people = context.Users.get.People();
  // Map over fields for expected return per user based on logic
  const filteredPeople = people.map(person => {
    if (person.name === "Foo") {
      return { name: person.name, age: person.age }
    } else {
      return { name: person.name };
    }
  });
  return filteredPeople;
};
```

In short, resolvers are what allow you to modify the returned information